# Пропадает граватар

Tags: дефект

После праздника с шляпами появился дефект в виде исчезающего граватара (используется дефолтный), а при наведении на него курсора выглядит как должен.

Вопрос не существенный, но всё же.

Кэш чистил.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не кеш самого граватара ли это?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму в других проектах все норм. это кеш шляпы ))

Comment: это может быть кеш граватарок определенного размера?

Comment: ага и вдруг он появляется сразу после шляп )

Comment: у @Nofate такое периодически